# Eclipse issue? Can't find java.security.SecureRandom in source packages

Tags: java, eclipse, build, ide, bcrypt

I've added the [jBCrypt](http://www.mindrot.org/projects/jBCrypt/) code to my project which attempts to use java.security.SecureRandom, and when I build I get the following error:

> java.security.SecureRandom can not be found in source packages. Check
>   the inheritance chain from your module; it may not be inheriting a
>   required module or a module may not be adding its source path entries
>   properly.

Now if I type `import java.security.SecureRandom` the auto-complete in Eclipse finds the class. If I look in my package explorer under /JRE System Library [jre7]/rt.jar/java.security.SecureRandom.class, I can click on that item and see the source file. I've been fussing with this for a couple of hours, so I finally decided to give in and see if anyone out there knows what might cause this.

I've tried removing the JRE library and then re-adding it to my project. I also tried specifically adding the rt.jar to my project. None of this seems to matter, it always just results in the same error.

It seems like I have the source code, but for some reason the class isn't in the JAR? Is that is what is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer buried in [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en&fromgroups=#!topic/google-web-toolkit/ozLSbA2909w)

It is a problem with the GWT WindowBuilder. To fix this issue I simply went to Window > Preferences > WindowBuilder > GWT > Builder and unchecked the box labeled "Check for 'client' classpath"

Here is [what this check box does](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/tools/gwtdesigner/preferences/gwt/preferences_builder)

This is why I hate IDEs.